# HealthCheckResult how to return additional info in response?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, health-monitoring

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckResult

public HealthCheckResult (Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthStatus status, string description = null, Exception exception = null, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string,object> data = null);

Parameters

status HealthStatus  
A value indicating the status of the component that was checked.

description String  
A human-readable description of the status of the component that was checked.

exception Exception  
An Exception representing the exception that was thrown when checking for status (if any).

data IReadOnlyDictionary<String,Object> 
Additional key-value pairs describing the health of the component.
```

Unfortunately trial-and-error shows that `description` is not returned in the health-check endpoint response.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return new HealthCheckResult(status: HealthStatus.Unhealthy, 
                                 description: ex.Message,
                                 exception: ex);
}
```

I'd think that the exception message would be returned in the response and displayed in the browser but it's not.

Is there an undocumented mechanism to return additional info beyond `Degraded` `Healthy` `Unhealthy` etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

The `HealthCheckResult` is a struct in .Net Core. In the implementation of method `CheckHealthAsync` of `IHealthCheck` interface, you can return the status along with custom description as below -

```
   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
          return HealthCheckResult.Healthy("connected successfully.");
   }
```

OR

```
return HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Failed to connect.)
```

Comment: Do you know why the `HealthCheckResult` with the extended constructor ( as I've edited my post ) does not return the `description` text ?

Comment: @BaltoStar I am not aware why ```HealthCheckResult``` extended constructor is not returning custom text. But as per Microsoft standard document, it is recommended to implement ```IHealthCheck``` and return status using ```HealthCheckResult``` struct as I have shown in my above example (which will return custom text). Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way in asp .net core 3.1 there is a second parameter that accepts a dictionary of string and object where you can add further information.